# Посадка темы на WordPress с помощью underscores

Tags: wordpress

В теме уже имеется файл style.css и в нем примерно 900 строк кода. Содержимое нам этого файла нужно? можно туда просто залить свои стили?

Comment: это стандартный style.css underscores . Он генерируется при создании

Comment: если генерируется то надо .... без вариантов

Comment: Более устаревший хлам, чем underscores, найти трудно

Comment: Берите любую понравившуюся тему из репозитория WordPress, делайте от нее дочернюю, и работайте.